# How to get started with robotics having no idea what it is

Tags: robotics

I wanted to learn robotics, Actually i want to build a robot not very complex but atleast that makes sense of what it does. So basically im a cs student who knows only about programming and nothing about microcontroller or anything remotely close to that particular subject. I know little about electronics but never dug deep into that.

So i need an advice on how to start on my journey of learning robotics where i have no idea about the above mentioned fields

Ive seen in lot of article where u have to learn maths (obviously) and adruino. I've  seen them telling to use adruino ide and even use python language or c/c++
But atleast for now what would be the difderence between these two. Does adruino directly compile the code to machine level language or it is just that its easier to do so in adruino

Thanks for going through the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to start with Robotics, You should know the fundamentals of machine learning that are

1. [Computer Vision](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/computer-vision-giving-vision-to-machines-fd777c1c678c)
2. [Natural language processing](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/bayes-text-classification-machine-learning-algorithms-915d320abcdb)
3. [Artificial Neural networks](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/artificial-neural-networks-mapping-the-human-brain-2e0bd4a93160)
4. Deep understanding about learning       methods

The above points refer to the software which controls the robot.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It does help in understanding the most fundamentals of AI and automation of robots

Answer (score 0):

Robotics is really broad, to be able to get any help, you have to provide more details on the type of robots you are interested in. Robots can range from simple arduino robots that you can build in a few days to boston dynamics level robots :). But I would advise you start with the arduino. It is very easy and user-friendly and will get you warmed up. Then from there every other thing will become clearer.